# Tweet scraping--Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) : Forbidden (HTTP 403)

Tags: screen-scraping, new-operator, policy, tweets

searchTwitter('#Houston', n=1000, lang='en')--after using this code, I am getting the below error--
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) :
Forbidden (HTTP 403).

Is this because of the new Twitter policy implemented on 29th Sept 2023?

"Twitter, now owned by Elon Musk, has updated its terms of service to ban scraping and crawling. The new terms, which went into effect on September 29, 2023, prohibit any scraping or crawling without prior written consent. This is likely to prevent AI models from training on Twitter's data."--from Social Media Today--https://www.socialmediatoday.com/news/twitter-implements-usage-limits-combat-data-scrapers/684831/

I am looking for a solution to this problem.